# General Classification of finite simple ternary groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Define a ternary group as an algebraic set endowed with a 3-ary operation f: that maps 3 elements onto another in the set.

Furthermore for any three elements a,b,c there exists a unique 4th element x such that

$$ f(a,b,x) = f(a,x,b) = f(x,a,b) = c $$

(Generalizing the idea of an inverse):

And

$$ f(f(a,b,c),d,e) = f(a,f(b,c,d),e) = f(a,b,f(c,d,e)) $$

(Generalizing the idea of associativity)

Has the classification of all finite simple structures satisfying these properties been done before?

Comment: When is such a structure simple? What is the notion of "normal" subgroup here?

Comment: thats a good point. I have no idea how to generalize those terms

Comment: perhaps a sub 3-ary group is easy to define. as simply a subset that is not a trivial "identity" element for which the same function is associative,closed, and carries inverses

Comment: So maybe a place to start would be to classify those of small order (say, up to like 5).

Comment: Why would you exclude the trivial subgroup?

Comment: Well the trivial subgroup is a standard one, I was thinking of defining non trivial subgroups, sort of like a prime factorization for these types of structures

Comment: Obviously associativity will be inherited by subgroups also for 3-ary structures. I wonder if the inverse requirement will also be automatic from closure in finite ones.

Comment: Universal algebra provides natural definitions that generalize those you find for groups, rings, etc. "Simple algebra" is probably the definition you seek. Unlike groups and rings, the congruence relations (eq-relations preserving the operations) may not correspond to a sub-(ternary group), so there may not be a natural definition of "normal". But there will be one for "simple". Standard results in universal algebra also imply isomorphism theorems for your structure, substructure theorems, etc. (If you include the inversion operation into your signature, Birkhoff's HSP theorem applies.)